# My input into the database wont work

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

```
import tkinter

from sqlite3 import *

def mDestroy():
    window.destroy()

def mClear():
    EName.delete(0, 'end')
    ESurname.delete(0, 'end')
    EDOB.delete(0, 'end')
    ETutorGroup.delete(0, 'end')
    EEmail.delete(0, 'end')

def mTable():
    with connect("PupilData.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pupil(
            PupilID integer,
            Name text,
            Surname text,
            DOB integer
            TutorGroup text,
            Email text,
            Primary Key(PupilID));""")
    db.commit()

mTable()

#def mInput():
#    Name = EName.get()
#    Surname = ESurname.get()
#    DOB = EDOB.get()
#    TutorGroup = ETutorGroup.get()
#    Email =  EEmail.get()
#    return
#with connect("PupilData.db") as db:
#    cursor = db.cursor()
#    sql = "Insert into Pupil (Name, Surname, DOB, TutorGroup, Email) values(?,?,?,?,?)"
#    cursor.execute (sql, (Name, Surname, DOB, TutorGroup, Email))
#    db.commit()
```

ever since I wrote line 32-42, my code does not work anymore and I don't know why.
I just can't figure it out and my group can't figure it out either. It's the code with the hashtags

```
#Button Commands    
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("New York registration")
window.geometry("500x800")


window.configure(background="royal blue")
```

Creates window amd all the attributes

```
TitleL =tkinter.Label(window,text='New York Registration 2018',bg='royal blue',fg='white',font = "verdana 15 bold").place(x=50,y=0)
NameL=tkinter.Label(window,  text ="Name",bg='royal blue',fg='white').place(x=50,y=200)
SurnameL = tkinter.Label(window, text="Surname",bg='royal blue',fg='white').place(x=50,y=250)
DOBL = tkinter.Label(window,  text="DOB",bg='royal blue',fg='white').place(x=50,y=300)
TutorGroupL = tkinter.Label(window,  text="TutorGroup",bg='royal blue',fg='white').place(x=50,y=350)
EmailL=tkinter.Label(window, text="Email",bg='royal blue',fg='white').place(x=50,y=400)
```

Creates Labels and all the attributes

```
EName =tkinter.Entry(window, highlightthickness=2, highlightbackground="Red", highlightcolor="Red")
ESurname =tkinter.Entry(window, highlightthickness=2 ,highlightbackground="Red", highlightcolor="Red")
EDOB =tkinter.Entry(window,highlightthickness=2,highlightbackground="Red",highlightcolor="Red")
ETutorGroup =tkinter.Entry(window,highlightthickness=2,highlightbackground="Red",highlightcolor="Red")
EEmail =tkinter.Entry(window,highlightthickness=2,highlightbackground="Red",highlightcolor="Red")
```

creates Entry boxes and all the attributes

```
EName.place(x=200,y=200)
ESurname.place(x=200,y=250)
EDOB.place(x=200,y=300)
ETutorGroup.place(x=200,y=350)
EEmail.place(x=200,y=400)
```

places the entry boxes

```
Submit =tkinter.Button(window,text="Submit",bg ='black',fg ='white',).place(x=50,y=450)
Clear =tkinter.Button(window,text="Clear", bg ='black',fg='white',command =mClear).place(x=100,y=450)
Exit = tkinter.Button(window,text = "Exit", bg='black',fg='white',command=mDestroy).place(x=150,y=450)
```

This creates all the buttons for my tkinter GUI and adds their attributes

```
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Does your query run in whatever management console you are using?

Comment: What is an RDBMS? Like, Oracle, or MS SQL. Does your SQL query run against your database? edit: Nevermind it's SQL Lite I didn't see that first sentence somehow.

Comment: The `db.commit()` should be inside `with` block

Comment: That didn't work, it says error Name- Name is not defin4d even though i have defined it

Comment: In your commented code `with connect("PupilData.db") as db` should be inside `def mInput():` and before `return`

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Does the program crash? Does it insert the wrong data into the database?